# Meaning of AlarmManager parameters

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

To set an alarm, I use

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureTimeInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

I don't understand the relation between `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` and `futureTimeInMillis`. For example, say I want an alarm to go off 15 minutes from now. Then what is the value of `futureTimeInMillis`? is it

```
futureTimeInMillis = NOW+MIN_15;
```

or is it

```
    futureTimeInMillis = MIN_15;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc [AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP):

> Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (**time since boot,
>   including sleep**), which will wake up the device when it goes off.

So it does not what that you actually want, i guess.

As for your question, [AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP) should be used for that with

```
futureTimeInMillis = NOW+MIN_15
```

Comment: changing to `RTC_WAKEUP` solves my problem. But I still don't understand `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`. And I read the docs before posting.

Comment: ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP—Wakes up the device and fires the pending intent after the specified length of time has elapsed since device boot.

Comment: So  for example if you use, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP with 3600000 then this will trigger your intent after hour from device boot.